# How to make animation for height using transform?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transform

I have a view. For example 200 width and 100 height. I want to animate view changing height from 200 height until 0 height. I feel like doing it using transform. How to do it?

Comment: do it with constraints

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    yourView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
}
```

If you want to animate your constraints, use the following:

```swift
myHeightConstraint.constant = 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: I want that myView remained in place and only the height changed. It needs move from bottom to top

Comment: Then you need to animate the constraints like @Lu_ said. I will update my answer

Comment: is it possible to it with transform?

Comment: transform would scale the view towards its anchor-point I guess

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing the initial height constraint constant value is 200 
then:-

```
view.layoutIfNeeded() 
animatedViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { 
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
})
```